# DataGridView live search data

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add a search function to a DataGridView in vb.net using this code

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ContactsList.RowCount - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To ContactsList.ColumnCount - 1
        If ContactsList.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString.ToLower.Trim = ContactsListSearch.Text.ToLower.Trim Then
            MsgBox("Item found " + i.ToString)
            ContactsList.Rows(i).Visible = True
        Else
            ContactsList.Rows(i).Visible = False
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I'm seeing the MsgBox show when the value matches, but the rows are not showing, it just hides all rows

Comment: Unless every column has the same value, sure, you are telling the grid to hide every row.

Comment: You may want to note that in its current state, the row will be visible/invisible depending ONLY on the value in the LAST column. Example if the value matches the search term in column one then that row gets set to visible, then on the next iteration of the columns loop IF the value in column 2 does NOT match the search term, THEN, the row is set to invisible. Only the last column in each row will dictate if the row is visible or not. I would think if you “found” the searched for value… then you would set the row visible and `break` out of the columns loop.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option is to load data into a `DataTable`, create a `BindingSource`, set the [BindingSource](http://BindingSource) DataSource property to the DataTable. Set the `DataGridView` DataSource property to the BindingSource.

The following example works against a column in the DataTable. If the user clears the TextBox the filter is removed while if there is text filter with trim.

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _ 
    Handles SearchButton.Click

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchTextBox.Text) Then
        bindingSource.Filter = ""
    Else
        Dim currentRowCount = bindingSource.Count
        bindingSource.Filter = $"TRIM(LastName) = '{SearchTextBox.Text}'"
        MessageBox.Show($"Before: {currentRowCount} Now: {bindingSource.Count}")
    End If

End Sub
```

**Edit** If the column name might be variable consider loading a ComboBox with column names then adjust code as follows.

```
bindingSource.Filter = $"TRIM({FilterComboBox.Text}) = '{SearchTextBox.Text}'"
```

In most cases working against a data source is better than working against cells values as per the above recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I added 2 Exits in the IF statement when the value matches as it's searching each column as well, so it was causing them to be hidden as it loops columns too

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ContactsList.RowCount - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To ContactsList.ColumnCount - 1
        If ContactsList.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString.ToLower.Trim = ContactsListSearch.Text.ToLower.Trim Then
            MsgBox("Item found " + i.ToString)
            ContactsList.Rows(i).Visible = True
        Else
            ContactsList.Rows(i).Visible = False
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I am sorry if I am missing something, however, I do not see any “difference” between the code in the question and the code in this answer. In other words… how does the “same” code solve your problem? Can you explain?